# The hot burner light on my Kenmore glass top range stays on all the time, is it dangerous to leave this alone and not fix it?

Tags: stove

My Kenmore glasstop range hot burner light stays on all the time, is this dangerous?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to know without more information, but my personal guess is not. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 3):

In the sense that it no longer serves its function (it's on all the time, so it's no longer an indication that you should be cautious of a hot surface,) there's some danger that you might get burned, or set down something that melts or catches fire when there actually IS a hot surface, since that's not otherwise visibly obvious.

Other than that, I don't think there's any danger to having the light on, as such. Just treat the thing as if the light was accurate, so as not to get burned when it is accurate.